# iOS 16 WKWebView is taking too much time to load html string

Tags: ios, ios16

I am using Xcode 14 Beta3 for running my app on iOS 16 beta version. In iOS 16 beta WKWebView is taking too much time to load giving this message:

WKWebview[49047:766241] [Process] WebContent process (0x110060100) took 3.068095 seconds to launch WKWebview[49047:766241] [Process] 0x110060100 - [PID=49612] WebProcessProxy::didBecomeUnresponsive: WKWebview[49047:766241] [Process] 0x7fafa101f420 - [pageProxyID=6, webPageID=7, PID=49612] WebPageProxy::processDidBecomeUnresponsive: WKWebview[49047:766241] [Process] Networking process (0x110064210) took 3.092397 seconds to launch WKWebview[49047:766241] [Process] GPU process (0x11009c4e0) took 3.586429 seconds to launch

In iOS 15 with Xcode 14 Beta3 it’s running fine. Could any one help me on this?

Also I tried one POC with WKWebView where loading below html string. It’s also taking too much time in iOS 16 webView.loadHTMLString("Hello!Taking too much time on iOS 16", baseURL: nil)

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are a _beta tester_. If a beta ruins the behavior of your code, _report it to Apple_.

Comment: I have added here in apple forum: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712349

Comment: Could any one help me here if someone has faced same issue

Comment: Apple forum is not the same as filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I have put it here as well. https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/11299538